# Conectar con BBDD en xamarin forms con SQLite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

estoy intentando crear una cadena de conexión con SQLite para poder coger mi BBDD y no tener que guardarla en proyecto pero no soy capaz de conseguirlo.

¿Cómo podría crear la conexión? He intentado con SqliteConnectionStringBuilder pero no consigo hacerlo.

Gracias!

Comment: la BBDD ya la tengo creada, solamente sería generar el código para llamar a esa BBDD

Comment: Coloca el codigo que hiciste

Comment: pues la verdad esque por el cabreo que me cogí quité el código jaja, porque una pregunta, en sql server si consigo abrir la cadena de conexión, pero en google encuentro siempre el sqlite, para app móvil se puede usar sql server?

Comment: tenes que usar una Api que s conecte con tu sqlserver.

Comment: gracias! buscare como hacer una Api, esque soy nuevo en esto y algunas cosas me están costando mas de lo normal

Comment: ya te ayudo con la conexion a sqlite

Comment: pone tu clases que vas a usar como tablas, para que la ayuda se mas concreta

Comment: gracias, lo que pasa que la tabla ya la tengo creada, con lo que me ahorro crearme una clase, lo que quiero hacer es cuando tenga abierta la cadena de conexión, en la pagina de login, al poner un usuario y contraseña concreto, vaya a su app y si pongo otro, vaya a su app, ya que lo que cambian son logotipos y algunos textos